# Start / Stop OpenVPN client on machine with OpenVPN server running (command line)

Tags: server, openvpn, client

I have an *Ubuntu 14.04* Server with an *OpenVPN Server* running on it.
Now for backup purposes I want this machine to create a VPN connection to a seperate machine.

I figured out that I can create a new client instance using this code:

```
openvpn --config openvpn.ovpn --auth-user-pass auth --auth-nocache --nobind &
```

where "*auth*" is a file containing a username and password for the connection.

This seems work fine, but the problem is that I have no idea how to close the connection after it has been opened (I do not know if this is the best solution).

I only need the connection during a backup process and it is important that the VPN server stays active, so solutions like "*killall*" and "*restart*" are not an option.

The Ubuntu Server is running without a User Interface. So I can only use command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get ID of your process:

`openvpn --config openvpn.ovpn --auth-user-pass auth --auth-nocache --nobind > /dev/null & pid=$!`

Stop that process:

`kill $pid`

Comment: Definitely works for root. That should be fine. Thanks.

Comment: Just one addition: Will the server and client get in each others way when doing this?

Comment: only if you try to bind both to same interface (tap0 or tun0). make client to work in different subnet on another interface - and you can connect to as many server as you like.